# Finding unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull items from a certain table that match between month 11 2018 ans month 11 2019, to get the number of unique items retained. The table looks something like the below. How do I obtain this result?

```
ItemId, Store#, Year, Month
1234, 21, 2018, 11
2345, 22, 2019, 11
1234, 21, 2019, 11
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM yourtable WHERE (Year*100) + Month BETWEEN 201811 AND 201911;` would probably get you in the ballpark.

Comment: What is your expected result? 2?

Comment: @JNevil that got me at least the base, thanks

Comment: What more were you looking for. I took your "get the number of unique items retained" at face value, but perhaps "Retained" means there is some math that needs to be done? Like a count of inventory before and after or something?

Comment: there actually was, so i was looking to see how many of the item Ids existed from 11/2018 through 11/2019 and have not fallen off. So your code gave me the base, that is, how many items are there now, just not how many of those were retained. So it is like x number of item ids have been retained from the total of y number of total item ids. S that gave me the y part.

Comment: That gave you the X part. You should update your question with your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to filter on `year` and `month`, but they are in different columns.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.year * 12 + month >= 2018 * 12 + 11 and
      t.year * 12 + month <= 2019 * 12 + 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordons answer will filter rows correctly. Adding `COUNT(DISTINCT())` will give you the number of unique items.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.ItemId)) AS NumUnique
FROM t
WHERE t.year * 12 + month >= 2018 * 12 + 11
AND t.year * 12 + month <= 2019 * 12 + 11
;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Skip those extra parentheses to write clearer code, i.e. simply `COUNT(DISTINCT t.ItemId)`.

Comment: @jarlh SQL flavour is not mentioned. In MySQL, at least, DISTINCT works both with and without parenthesis. I'm used to using it with parenthesis, but you are correct. It's probably better to remove them.